# How to pass variable from child to child in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have three components : **parent (P)**  and **two children (C1)** and **(C2)** 
(they are **both children of P** component and they are **not nested**) 
in parent template it looks like

```
<c1-component></c1-component>
<c2-component></c2-component>
```

I have a variable `myVar` in `C1` (number), which I want decrease and increase in `C2` component and give a new value of this variable back to `C1` (so, I want to pass not a function, but variable). How could I pass this variable from `C1` to `C2`?
I would like to solve this problem without shared services.

Comment: You can try like that <c1 (out)=#temp2.var></c1> <c2 #temp2></c2>. (out) represent an output param using event emitter. #temp2 is a template reference variable. Create component variable var in component child 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could emit the variable from child1 using a EventEmitter to the parent. Catch it as an input within the parent and then pass it to child2 within the selector.

Child 1:

```
import { Output } from '@angular/core';
@Output() testVariable = new EventEmitter();
```

Catch within parent and emit in Parent html:

```
<c2-component [testVariable]="testVariable"></c2-component>
```

Child 2:

```
import { Input} from '@angular/core';
@Input() testVariable;
```

Comment: Please explain why this was downvoted? It is working code in my own solution. Thanks

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe it's related to because you answered a question that was marked as a duplicate, you can read how to handle duplicate question: [How should duplicate questions be handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Comment: @Wilcko this solution is good and it's a different, thanks